# Excel processing throws exception 'NoSuchMethodError' on Formula Evaluator for .xlsx file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem while processing excel files.
Processing of excel is working fine for .xls file.
But it throws the following exception when it process .xlsx file on the Formula Evaluator. Is there a common method to get Formula Evaluator for .xls and xlsx or need to write seperate code? I am using poi-3.10.1

Exception is right there at the following code:

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
```

It throws the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.<init>(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/EvaluationWorkbook;Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/IStabilityClassifier;Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/record/formula/udf/UDFFinder;)V
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.<init>(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.<init>(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator(XSSFCreationHelper.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator(XSSFCreationHelper.java:21)
```

Comment: How are you creating it currently? You should be using [`WorkBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();`](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)

Comment: I creating it using this FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

Comment: Could you share OOXML version? You need to make sure POI and OOXML versions are same.

Comment: I was using poi-ooxml-3.6. I have tried poi-3.6 and poi-ooxml-3.6 also but no difference

Comment: With  poi-3.6 and poi-ooxml-3.6, could you try like this XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [Apache POI FAQ entry on this very topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006). Basically, you have a mixture of old and new POI jars on your classpath, which is confusing things and is [explicitly not a supported option](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C)

You need to go through your classpath, and remove any old or mis-matched POI jars, leaving just the jars from the latest Apache POI release. If you can't figure out what jars you're using, you can make use of [the code in the FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) to help you find out

With all the old jars gone, add in the latest ones ([currently 3.12](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html)), including their [dependencies if not using Maven](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), and your code will then be fine!

Comment: Actually the old version of jar files were there at the class path location but did not specified that old jars in class path. This created the issue. Even if we did not specify the old jars in class path the old jars should be removed from class path location